# How to order by time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, time

I have column (string type) in my database (postgres) => "time"
I'd like order by the "time" but it doesn't work.

I get all data by:

```
@results.order(:time).all;
```

And my list looks like this

```
1:00:12
31:31
45:12
51:33
```

How can I order this? Maybe is it possible to do in postgres by cast the column or by gsub in rails? Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: It works, your results are sorted properly.

Comment: the column type is `string` - therefor it orders like that.

Answer (score 4):

The right way to store **time** stuff in rails is to use the time format. i.e.:

```
create_table :results do |t|
  t.time :name_of_attributes
end
```

Then you can easily sort via:

```
@results.all.order(:time => :asc)
```

reference : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

EDIT:

As suggested by @Vucko, the asker might want to have it formatted as a string in the database. In that case, it should not be too hard to just add some relevant method:

```
# Add the following method to the `Result` model:

def parse_time
  res = 0
  time.split(":").reverse.each_with_index do |val, index|
    res += val.to_i * (60 ** index)
  end
  res
end

# Then to sort it
@results.all.sort_by do |a, b|
  a.parse_time <=> b.parse_time
end
```

I should clarify that the second method is NOT preferred as it can be slower.

Comment: Maybe there is a reason why the OP uses `string` for the type?

Comment: I assume he just didn't know the `time` type exists